How to write polymorphic rule in latest K framework?
I've got a problem then writing the rule returning NUM bits starting from P position in MInt. So I writing an analogue of this from Kframework 5 version:
/*@ extractMask(MI, W, S) Extracts the lower W bits
    from MInt starting from lower significant bit position S.

    Ex: extractMask(MI, 16, 8):
        MI:64' 0x 00 ff 00 ff 00 ff 00 ff
        Output:                  <--->
          MI:16' 0x                 ff 00

    extractMask(MI, 4, 1)
      6 5 4 3 2 1 0
      * * * * * * *
          ------^

    extractMask(MI, NUM, P) <==> extractMInt(MI, S , S + NUM)
      where S = bitwidthMInt(MI) - (P + NUM)

    Example, extractMInt(MI, 2, 6) // Bits in range [2..6)

      0 1 2 3 4 5 6
      * * * * * * *
          ^-------^
  */
  rule extractMask(MI, NUM, P) => 
  extractMInt(MI, bitwidthMInt(MI) -Int P -Int NUM, bitwidthMInt(MI) -Int P)
    requires (P +Int NUM) <=Int bitwidthMInt(MI)

I've rewrite it with newer MInt bit operations
syntax {WidthIn, WidthOut} MInt{WidthOut} ::= extractMask(MInt{WidthIn}, Int, Int) [function]

rule extractMask(MI, NUM, P) =>
      (MI &MInt Int2MInt(umaxMInt(P +Int NUM))) >>lMInt Int2MInt(P) 
      requires (P +Int NUM) <=Int bitwidthMInt(MI)

But when kompile got error
[Error] Compiler: Illegal function symbol
extractMask(_,_,_)_TEST_MInt_MInt_Int_Int on LHS of rule. Consider adding
`simplification` attribute to the rule if this is intended.
    Source(/home/nonroot/test.k)
    Location(41,10,41,33)
    41 |        rule extractMask(MI, NUM, P) =>
       .             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Adding [simplification] to the rule leads to
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.runtimeverification.k.kore.implementation$ConcreteClasses$SortVariable cannot be cast to class com.runtimeverification.k.kore.CompoundSort (com.runtimeverification.k.kore.implementation$ConcreteClasses$SortVariable and com.runtimeverification.k.kore.CompoundSort are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.kframework.backend.llvm.matching.Parser$SymLib.sortAtt(Parser.scala:136)
    at org.kframework.backend.llvm.matching.pattern.SortCategory$.getBitwidth(SortCategory.scala:61)
    at org.kframework.backend.llvm.matching.pattern.SortCategory$.apply(SortCategory.scala:51)
    at org.kframework.backend.llvm.matching.SortInfo.<init>(Matrix.scala:305)
    at org.kframework.backend.llvm.matching.SortInfo$.$anonfun$apply$1(Matrix.scala:316)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1220)
    at org.kframework.backend.llvm.matching.SortInfo$.apply(Matrix.scala:316)
    at org.kframework.backend.llvm.matching.Fringe.<init>(Matrix.scala:243)
    at org.kframework.backend.llvm.matching.Matrix$$anonfun$$lessinit$greater$1.apply(Matrix.scala:528)
    at org.kframework.backend.llvm.matching.Matrix$$anonfun$$lessinit$greater$1.apply(Matrix.scala:528)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.map(Range.scala:59)
    at org.kframework.backend.llvm.matching.Matrix.<init>(Matrix.scala:528)
    at org.kframework.backend.llvm.matching.Generator$.genClauseMatrix(Generator.scala:220)
    at org.kframework.backend.llvm.matching.Generator$.mkDecisionTree(Generator.scala:231)
    at org.kframework.backend.llvm.matching.Matching$.$anonfun$writeDecisionTreeToFile$2(Matching.scala:78)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:79)
    at org.kframework.backend.llvm.matching.Matching$.writeDecisionTreeToFile(Matching.scala:65)
    at org.kframework.backend.llvm.matching.Matching.writeDecisionTreeToFile(Matching.scala)
    at org.kframework.backend.llvm.LLVMBackend.accept(LLVMBackend.java:68)
    at org.kframework.kompile.KompileFrontEnd.run(KompileFrontEnd.java:114)
    at org.kframework.main.FrontEnd.main(FrontEnd.java:60)
    at org.kframework.main.Main.runApplication(Main.java:127)
    at org.kframework.main.Main.runApplication(Main.java:117)
    at org.kframework.main.Main.main(Main.java:58)
[Error] Internal: Uncaught exception thrown of type ClassCastException
(ClassCastException: class
com.runtimeverification.k.kore.implementation$ConcreteClasses$SortVariable
cannot be cast to class com.runtimeverification.k.kore.CompoundSort
(com.runtimeverification.k.kore.implementation$ConcreteClasses$SortVariable and
com.runtimeverification.k.kore.CompoundSort are in unnamed module of loader
'app'))

INT and MINT modules are imported
Kframework --version :
K version:  v7.1.137-0-g80310780c3-dirty
Build date:   Mon Sep 09 10:06:33 UTC 2024

